# Does fixed classes exist in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, classification, voronoi-thiessen

I'd like to create several images of voronois polygons in QGIS; each images having differents values joined to the voronois.
I tried to load a qml style with the values I want to keep (8 classes : 0>700, 700>1400, 1400>2100, ..., 4900>5600) for all my images, but it doesn't work when I pick the column of values I'd like to classify into the voronois: the maximum value of the picked column replaces then the one I'd like it to be the maximum (5600).
Would you know a way to apply that same classification to the differents values I have? For instance through fixed classes?